# New medinilla magnifica leaves curl and turn brown

Tags: diagnosis

I've got this medinilla magnifica that is doing really good. It bloomed beautifully an is growing some new leaves. However, every new leave curls and turns brown a few weeks after sprouting. This is only happening to new leaves. Below picture shows such a leave.

[image: new leave turned brown]

Does anyone know what could be causing this?